# Bash to append array value to file before copying

Tags: bash

The `bash` (thank you @Charles Duffy) stores each `uniqueid` in an `array` and then passes them to `%q` to get the unique path. That seems to work what I am having trouble with is renaming each `.png` with the unique value in `%q`. I thought it was working but upon closer inspection, a `.png` file is being sent to `scp`.... but only `1` and with the wrong `uniqueid`. It seems like the first `.png` is being used by `scp`, but with the last `uniqueid`. In this example there are 2, but there may be more or less. Thank you :).

```
printf -v cmd_q '(cd /path/to/%q*/*/*/folder && exec sshpass -f file.txt scp -- *.png* xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:'"$dir"'/folder/%q*-data.png)\n' "${array[@]}"
sshpass -f out.txt ssh -o strictHostKeyChecking=no -t xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xx "$cmd_q"
```

**array**

```
uniqueid1   ---- this is stored in array ----
data.png    ---- this is the file in the path ----

uniqueid2   ---- this is stored in array ----
data.png    ---- this is the file in the path ---
```

**current**

```
uniqueid1-data.png (but this is really the first png just with the wrong name)
```

**desired file transfered by scp**

```
uniqueid1-data.png
uniqueid2-data.png
```

**declare -p array**

```
declare -a array='([0]="ID1" [1]="ID2")'


getRNA_BAM.sh: line 45: declare: (cd /path/to/ID1*/*/folder && exec sshpass -f file.txt scp -- *.png* xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:path/to/destination/ID1-cn_results.png)\n: not found
getRNA_BAM.sh: line 45: declare: ID1 not found

getRNA_BAM.sh: line 45: declare: (cd /path/to/ID2*/*/folder && exec sshpass -f file.txt scp -- *.png* xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:path/to/destination/ID2-cn_results.png)\n: not found
getRNA_BAM.sh: line 45: declare: ID2 not found
```

**declare -p cmd_q**

```
declare -- cmd_q="(cd /path/to/ID1*/*/folder && exec sshpass -f file.txt scp -- *.png* xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:path/to/destination/ID1-cn_results.png)

                  (cd /path/to/ID2*/*/folder && exec sshpass -f file.txt scp -- *.png* xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:path/to/destination/ID2-cn_results.png)
```

I can manually `ssh` into directory and the `.png` is there, though it is only `cn_results` before the `scp` where it is renamed/ append with the `array` value and copied.

```
I tried to add the loop to scp and rename as such:
for ID in "${array[@]}" ; do
scp "$ID" xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:path/to/destination/"${ID%.png}"-cn_results.png )
done
```

Comment: Please add output of `declare -p array` and `declare -p cmd_q` to your question.

Comment: ...are you saying that your array interleaves keys and values? I don't believe the final post-edit version of your prior question indicated as much, but it's a little tricky to know what you mean by the "this is stored in array" / "this is stored in the path" comments (which is why I'm asking for the `declare -p` output, which will make it unmistakably clear what the arrays *actually* contain).

Comment: Do not `declare -p "$array"` but `declare -p array` without `$` `is renaming each .png` - you have to iterate over pngs, not `scp *.png*` all of them.

Comment: I will add `declare -p array` soon. Thank you :).

Comment: I updated the post with bot declare -p and tried to rename with a loop and `scp` with the same result. Thank you :).

Comment: so are you saying I need to iterate over each.`png` rename withe `%q` and then `scp`? Thank you :).